# AlchemyAPI - set default language while using HTML API: Sentiment Analysis

Tags: sentiment-analysis, alchemyapi

I'm trying to use the AlchemyAPI to run a sentiment analysis on a number of URLs. Because these URLs have their own set of parameters, I'm getting the data using `HTTP.get`, then running Alchemy's `HTMLGetTextSentiment` on the html that is returned:

```
getSentiment: (url) ->
    html = HTTP.get url

    res = HTTP.get "http://access.alchemyapi.com/calls/html/HTMLGetTextSentiment?html=#{html}&apikey=<key>&outputMode=json"
    res
```

This all works perfectly... Except half the time it thinks the content is the wrong language and throws an error. I happen to know that 100% of these pages will contain only English-language content, so is there a way to bypass the language detector and hard-code the language into the request?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a Meteor question, mis-tagged?

Comment: Sorry about that! It originally had more to do with Meteor, but I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try the following:

```
res = HTTP.get "http://access.alchemyapi.com/calls/html/HTMLGetTextSentiment?html=#{html}&apikey=<key>&outputMode=json&language=english"
```

The **language=english** parameter addition is the important part.

A similar approach worked for me.